# How can I be sure that I get an authentic response of a requested IP address?

Tags: dns, ip, isp, spoofing, hijack

Normally you perform a login to your ISP using the given user credentials. You then get allocated an IP address and get access to their internal name servers, so that you can ask for a certain domain name and get an IP address in response.

But how can I be sure that I retrieve the actual site I am asking for? How can I be sure that my ISP is not faking IPs or that they are not redirecting me to "faked internal servers" (with or without an identical ip address)? For example: If I ask for example.com, get its IP and they show me a simple clone of that site..

How is it made sure that an IP only exist once? It is possible to change the IP of localhost to something else, so what makes sure this is not happening with web addresses?

Of course: if the ISP would fake the destination, other users would get affected as well, if they request the same result. But even in this case: Wouln't it be possible to filter users by its ISP credentials and hijack them?

Probably there is some kind of misunterstanding in my way of understanding. But I don't get what I am missing.

Comment: If your ISP is malicious, there’s probably very little you can do — you can’t talk to anybody else without going through them, so you’re at their mercy. But as long as you’re dealing with a major, reputable ISP, this doesn’t seem likely. (Although if the court orders them to mess with you, they might.) Attacks by third parties are a bigger threat; see the answers.

Comment: So all we can do is trust. well.. I am unsure if a decentralized internet or some sort of IP encryption would fix this security flaw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, DNS is insecure. If you really want to know that you're talking to the server you wanted, you must authenticate the server. So that's what we do. We don't trust DNS to be secure, and we implement the security we need somewhere else, such as TLS (Transport-Layer Security).

TLS (the modern security layer of HTTPS) does this by forcing the server to send the client a certificate stating the server's name and public key. This cert is cryptographically signed by a trusted third party called a Certificate Authority (CA). The CA signature vouches that the cert shows the correct public key for the named server.

To prove the server is the rightful owner of the cert (and not some impostor that stole a valid cert), the TLS handshake makes it prove that it knows the secret private key that forms a matched set with the public key in the cert. This is done without revealing the private key itself, of course.

There's a proposal for securing DNS called DNSsec, but it's been kicking around for years and never seems to go anywhere. It may never become widely deployed. There's now a proposal for "DNS over HTTP" (DoH, pronounced "D'oh!") that could secure DNS by doing it over HTTPS.

Comment: I am speaking of OSI layer 3 , not layer 5. Please check my comment to mshafer. It is not controlable how the ISP routes your request, is it? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_routing

Comment: @NgwVLHUeang, you're correct the ISP could route you wherever they want.  That's why we use things like TLS to verify the destination rather than the route, as the answer says.

Answer (score 0):

Lot's of questions there. I'll try to tackle a couple.

> But how can I be sure that I retrieve the actual site I am asking for?
>   How can I be sure that my ISP is not faking IPs or that they are not redirecting me to "faked internal servers" (with or without an identical ip address)?
>   For example: If I ask for example.com, get its IP and they show me a simple clone of that site..

So, this is called a man-in-the-middle attack (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). The bad news is that they are fairly common (at least on hotels and other places with open wifi, although also kind of hard to prove, - https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/06/01/teamviewer_mass_breach_report/). But one way to safeguard against is to not use the hotel's (or in your case your ISP's) DNS server. There are a couple of good ones out there: https://www.howtogeek.com/122845/htg-explains-what-is-dns/

I would be surprised if a reputable ISP does this (and is caught), but using your own DNS (again your still trusting someone) and/or a VPN whenever you're not on the home network is a good idea.

Comment: @Spiff - I don't have enough credit points to upvote your answer, but :thumbs_up:

Comment: I was more referring to the set up of IP addresses, instead of the actual domain name system. At insecure locations such as hotels, airports etc. I know that it is not safe to browse without HTTPS or a secured connection such as VPN, to protect passwords and privacy.

What I am thinking: It is never secure to access "8.8.8.8" from your home network, as you never can be sure to get an authentic response of Google. You have to trust your ISP to get the real page and not a mirrored clone. You can not validate what 8.8.8.8 stands for. As it is on your ISPs decision what data route he chooses.

Comment: And HTTPS does not save you from this. As the ISP could set up its own CA to get a green lock for a cloned website.

Comment: @NgwVLHUeang It seems like https *would* save you from this, since you're supposed to be going to the original website that matches the trusted certificate from your trusted CA - a spoofed clone site would fail the CA check.

Comment: I don't get it..  I was talking of a faked CA, with the believe that IP addresses can be manipulated by ISPs and the possibility to change the online route.. 

First I'd rather get a answer for the basic question: "Can ISPs change the way of handling with requested IP addresses?"

Comment: @NgwVLHUeang You never talk to the CA, so an evil ISP can't mess with that. The CA's cert (and thus its public key) was pre-installed in your OS or browser. It is not downloaded live. You use the CA public key that you already know and trust to verify the CA's pre-existing cryptographic signature on the cert of the server you're connecting to.

Comment: Good point. I checked it, the OS are coming with root certificates for the CA.  Then it seems to be working as you said. Thank you